# How to turn Cheerio DOM nodes back into html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cheerio

Using the HTML below, I'm attempting to extract the html of each paragraph. However I cannot find any way to turn the nodes back into HTML or query objects.

The below is a string `var html = ...`

```
<article>
    <p> p1 </p>
    <p> p2 </p>
</article>
```

The html is loaded as such

```
var $ = require('cheerio').load(html)
var paragraphs = $('p').toArray().map(p => /* I want the html at this point */ )
```

How to I get the HTML of these paragraphs?

NOTE: for clarity I'm calling the return value of `cheerio.load` a "query object" and the return of the `toArray` method DOM nodes; for lack of a better phrase.

Comment: `Element.outerHTML`?

Comment: 'outerHTML' is not a property of the node. And before it comes up, yes I have the latest version of Cheerio :P

Comment: `outerHTML` is a standard property on DOM elements.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is! But I'm asking about how to use Cheerio for this. I can do it with JSDOM just fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `$.html`:

```
var paragraphs = $('p').toArray().map(p => {
    console.log($.html(p));
    return $.html(p);
});
```

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#rendering) shows an example using a selector, however cheerio DOM elements also work as expected:

> If you want to return the outerHTML you can use $.html(selector):
>
> `$.html('.pear') //=> <li class="pear">Pear</li>`