# Node to select/extract html/text using CSS Selector from HTML

Tags: html, node.js, css-selectors

Suppose I'm writing a node script that uses `fetch` to have retrieved a html page content into a variable.

Now I have a CSS Selector for such content. How I can use it to extract the html and/or text content identified by my CSS Selector.

If there are existing tools/packages I can leverage, please give two level of answers:

1. Pure CSS Selector based
2. jQuery based tools

Comment: truly, first results using your phrases bring [How to turn Cheerio DOM nodes back into html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767347/how-to-turn-cheerio-dom-nodes-back-into-html).. you should at least edit the title, and preferably include some reproducible code, it hardly makes any sense what you're trying to do and what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

To extract HTML/text content identified by a CSS selector in Node.js, you can use various packages such as Cheerio, jsdom, or Puppeteer. Here are examples of how to extract content using CSS Selector for both pure CSS Selector based and jQuery-based tools:

Pure CSS Selector based:
Cheerio is a fast and flexible package that parses HTML and allows you to use CSS selectors to extract data. Here's how to use Cheerio to extract content using a CSS selector:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = '<html><body><div class="content">Hello World!</div></body></html>';

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const content = $('.content').text();

console.log(content); // Output: Hello World!
```

jQuery-based tools:
If you prefer jQuery syntax, you can use packages like jQuery or JSDOM. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const html = '<html><body><div class="content">Hello World!</div></body></html>';
const dom = new JSDOM(html);
const $ = require('jquery')(dom.window);

const content = $('.content').text();

console.log(content); // Output: Hello World!
```

In both examples, we first load the HTML content using a package (Cheerio or JSDOM), and then use a CSS selector to select the content we want. Finally, we extract the text of the selected element using the text() method.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for such detailed answer! I'll have to wait till 10 minutes later to accept your answer. Welcome aboard with my +25!

Comment: Oh, how to get html raw content? I tried `const htmlContent = $('.content')` from the cheerio one, but that's not quite right. So  sample code & cheerio doc ref needed please.